# How to lookup with value of a collection and key of anather collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

Example:

```
collectionA:
doc 1
    {
      _id:001,
      name:'A',
      day:'sun'
    }
doc 1
    {
      _id:001,
      name:'B',
      day:'Mon'
    }
```

This document goes on..
collectionB:

```
doc1
    {
     _id:201,
    classNames:{
              A:{
               student:true
              },
              B:{
              student:true
              }
             }
    },
    {
     _id:202,
    classNames:{
              A:{
               student:false
              },
              B:{
              student:true
              }
             }
    }
```

In the above example, I have to do a lookup. So how can I achieve this when the local field is the value of the name field and the foreign field will be the key of collection B. I just need to get the count also.

I have tried many aggregation methods, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear, but I think you want something like:

```
db.collA.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collB",
      let: {name: "$name"},
      pipeline: [
        {$project: {
            classNames: {$filter: {
                input: {$objectToArray: "$classNames"},
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k", "$$name"]}
            }}
        }},
        {$match: {"classNames.0": {$exists: true}}},
        {$project: {isStudent: {$first: "$classNames.v.student"}}}
      ],
      as: "classes"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SJiBXtwB92M)

- But if this is the case your structure is not an efficient one.